# Network boot of Windows Defender Offline will not update

Tags: networking, update, pxe-boot, anti-virus, wds

I have been working on configuring a network bootable virus removal suite, and I am using the Windows Defender WinPE iso generated from using [this 64-bit tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline). The tool downloads and creates an ISO for you. I extract the ISO in order to get the source boot.wim file and I make the following edits with the DISM tool:

- Mount the WIM file locally using DISM
- Remove bootfix.bin file (Removes "Press Any Key to Boot from CD/DVD.." message)
- Drop two files, mpam-fex64.exe & FilesList64.dll into the root of the wim file (Most current definitions at time of downloading)
- Add generic networking drivers to allow older machines to get a DHCP address
- Commit changes to WIM file and unmount it

Once all that is done, I transfer the boot.wim file to my Windows Deployment Server and add it as a boot image. Clients are now able to boot into the environment, here is the process:

```
Client Network Boot > DHCP Request > PXE Boot Screen > Windows Deployment Services > Virus Removal Environment
```

Once the client machine is booted into this environment, you can scan your computer or update the virus definitions, but any time I try to update the definitions, it fails due to a network error and gives me the error code `0x80004005.`

Things I have tried:

- Putting Client machine on an outside VLAN (results in `0x80072ee7` error code)
- Using `ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew` while in the environment
- Disabling the firewall via command line while in the environment
- Giving the program / user accounts involved write access to the WDS Server
- I wrote a script that automatically downloaded new updates, injected them into the image, and re-uploaded it to the server. But for whatever reason, each time this would occur it would fatten the WinSxS folder by ~80mb, so this quickly grew to an unreasonable size.

Any research of the two error codes given has been somewhat unsuccessful, they seem to be more of general windows update / networking errors. Unless someone is seeing something I didn't.

---

So with all of that given information, my question is: **Why is my Network Bootable WDO environment not able to update?**

Any insight is appreciated, let me know if you need additional information

Comment: Are network drivers installed in that environment?

Comment: @CanadianLuke, Yes, network drivers were injected into the environment, and I can verify that the machine is receiving a valid DHCP address through the command prompt available

Comment: Does it still grow by 80mb per update if you export-image to a new wim container (leaving behind replaced or removed files). 
`Dism /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:install.wim /SourceIndex:1 /DestinationImageFile:install2.wim`

Comment: My guess is it's the definitions, since mine worked and yours didn't.  Perhaps it thinks you want to use those (read-only?) definitions no matter what?

Answer (score 2):

This was such an AWESOME idea that I had to try it myself.  What I did was:

1. Open the iso to get the boot.wim file.
2. Mount the wim locally.
3. Inject a bunch of drivers offline for my environment.  (Not just older drivers, all of them.)
4. Drop the mpam-fex64.exe file into the top level of the wim.
5. Unmount the wim.
6. Add it to the WDS boot options.

Mine works flawlessly, successfully updating the definitions and auto-running Windows Defender without making me press a key.  I'm going to guess that either you're missing a network card driver or that something else got mangled while you were adding and removing files, as those are the only things we did differently.